# How do I populate Doctrine fields from PHP to complement form data?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a form which sends data from the server, which works just fine in Symfony, but what I don't know, is how can I set some fields by myself, like the `user_id` field, which I clearly don't want the user to send, I want to add the value for that just before Doctrine validates it.

Any relevant documentation links would be also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unset your fields in configure method:

```
class YourForm extends BaseYourForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    unset($this['user_id']);
  }
}
```

Override save method of Your model:

```
class Your extends BaseYour
{
  public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
  {
    $this->setUserId($whatever);    
    parent::save($conn);
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, but it helped me find the real solution, so I am giving it a vote up.

Comment: You should better give some feedback here: what didn't work and what is your solution. Thank you.